# Stirling's formula to bound infinite series

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to show the following bound, $$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-n\alpha}{(n\alpha)}^{n-1}}{n!} \leq \frac{1}{\alpha}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}  \frac{e^{-kI}}{\sqrt{2\pi n^3}} e^{-{(n-k)I}}$$

where $I=\alpha-1-\log(\alpha)$. I understand that I'm supposed to use Stirling's Formula but I'm lost as to how to do this and am not getting anywhere close. Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: On the RHS, what happens when you put in the value for $I$?  Also, can you see how to recombine the exponents on $e$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: For starting One may  give simple bounds valid for all positive integers $n$, rather than only for large $n$ using this [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

$\sqrt{2\pi n}n^{n}e^{-n}\leq n!\leq e n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}$, you can use the LHS of that inequality  which is :$\sqrt{2\pi n}n^{n}e^{-n}\leq n!$ implies :

$$\frac{1}{n!}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}n^{n}e^{-n}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n^3}e^{-n}}$$  , Mutltiplying  both sides by your needed factors and do summation you will come up to your bounds for $n^n$ in your dominator wich it would be still valid for $n^3$ in dominator